# Is it a good idea to use triggers to link to time dimension in fact tables in a dataware house?

Tags: optimization, triggers, data-warehouse

I am in the middle of design a data-ware house. There are multiple fact tables and its highly likely that hundreds of facts are inserted into each fact table. Even though its a bit early but still I was thinking of optimizations.

I have two tables for time

- date                      (unique row
  for each day)
- time of the day           (unique row
  for each minute in a day)

in all my fact tables I do have the full date column.

What does your experience say, should I used select statements in code to query the dimension Ids from time dimension table or I allow the time dimension columns in fact tables to be null able and  use triggers  to fill in the values?

Comment: lol when i read this question i thought i was on the physics forum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time-of-day dimensions are the (very unusual) case in the data warehousing when a surrogate key with "magic" values is beneficial. You can make primary keys in the date dimension integers with values like 20110516 and in the time-of-day dimensions either 1 - 1440 or 1 - 2400.

I suggest calculating corresponding values in your fact records and adding fields for them, say, CALENDAR_ID, TIME_OF_DAY_ID. Depending on the size of your data, you are likely to benefit from indexing on CALENDAR_ID and, maybe, even partitioning on it. If you are sure in the quality of your data, you can skip foreign key constraints on these fields to gain some performance during loading.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the magical values. Such tips are more than welcome. I just realized I can't vote up but thanks.

Comment: @WPFAbsoluteNewBie: If you cannot upvote, you can always accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- No nulls allowed for FKs in fact tables.
- Simply use your ETL to lookup keys from date and time dimension for each row of the fact table.
- No triggers in DW, all loading and key-lookup is done through the ETL application.

Comment: Thanks. that answers my question. But can you explain why I should not use triggers? of course when I said I will allow nulls I meant that I wont make them foreign keys as well.

Comment: @WPFAbsoluteNewBie, with EDWs you want to speed-up loading as much as possible. The are techniques for that and all ETL tools provide everything you need to load dimensions and facts. Having a trigger simply slows things down (fires on inserts/updates) and also moves an ETL step (lookup)outside your ETL application, so now you have two places to manage this.

Comment: @WPFAbsoluteNewBie, "Dimension columns in fact tables" are FKs.